# Images keep shifting depending on screen size. Can someone please help?

Tags: jquery, css, positioning, absolute, nivo-slider

Okay so I just spent 8 hours getting the nivo-slider installed and making it compatible with the main 3 browsers. Now when I get on my ipad to look at the screen the header is shifted to left although it looks fine on my laptop.

Can someone please view my source and give me suggestions, Thanks in advance!

My guess it has something to do with positioning, but can find which one, Thanks again

[www.gudskunc.com](http://www.gudskunc.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the site with as many browsers as you can: Safari, Chrome, Opera, Internet Explorer, etc. In Safari and Chrome, the banner is shifted to the left.

There are a bunch of things that need work, but a big one (and the fix here) is to structure things efficiently. Right now, your navbar, banner, and page content are all separate elements, and you use the ancient `center` tag to keep everything in the middle of the browser. Instead, scrap the `center` tags and wrap everything in one element...

```
<div id="container">
     <div id="header">
          ...
     </div>
     <div id="banner">
          ...
     </div>
     <div id="content">
          ...
     </div>
</div>
```

Then, in your CSS, you can easily center the whole thing at once:

```
#container { display: block; width: 950px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

Make sure that the structure of your HTML is making your life easier!

Comment: Thank you! About to get on it now! Thanks again!